# Is there a way to properly convert data from lists to a CSV file using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, list, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to create a webscraper for a website. The problem is that after the collected data is stored in a list, I'm not able to write this to a csv file properly. I have been stuck for ages with this problem and hopefully someone has an idea about how to fix this one!

The loop to get the data from the web pages:

```
import csv
from htmlrequest import simple_get
from htmlrequest import BeautifulSoup

# Define variables
listData = ['Companies', 'Locations', 'Descriptions']

plus = 15
max = 30
count = 0

# while loop to repeat process till max is reached
while (count <= max):
        start = 'https://www.companiesintheuk.co.uk/find?q=Activities+of+sport+clubs&start=' + str(count) + '&s=h&t=SicCodeSearch&location=&sicCode=93120'
        raw_html = simple_get(start)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'html.parser')
        for i, div in enumerate(soup.find_all('div', class_="search_result_title")):
            listData[0] = listData[0].strip() + div.text 

        for i, div2 in enumerate(soup.find_all('div', class_="searchAddress")):
             listData[1] = listData[1].strip() + div2.text  

# This is extra information
#        for i, div3 in enumerate(soup.find_all('div', class_="searchSicCode")):
#            listData[2] = listData[2].strip() + div3.text 

        count = count + plus
```

output example if printed:

```
Companies
(AMG) AGILITY MANAGEMENT GROUP LTD
(KLA) LIONS/LIONESS FOOTBALL TEAMS WORLD CUP LTD
(Dissolved)
1 SPORT ORGANISATION LIMITED
100UK LTD
1066 GYMNASTICS
1066 SPECIALS
10COACHING LIMITED
147 LOUNGE LTD
147 SNOOKER AND POOL CLUB (LEICESTER) LIMITED

Locations
ENGLAND, BH8 9PS
LONDON, EC2M 2PL
ENGLAND, LS7 3JB
ENGLAND, LE2 8FN
UNITED KINGDOM, N18 2QX
AVON, BS5 0JH
UNITED KINGDOM, WC2H 9JQ
UNITED KINGDOM, SE18 5SZ
UNITED KINGDOM, EC1V 2NX
```

I've tried to get it into a CSV file by using this code but I can't figure out how to properly format my output! Any suggestions are welcome.

```
# writing to csv
with open('test.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
            write = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            write.writerow(['Name','Location'])
            write.writerow([listData[0],listData[1]])

print("Writing has been done!")
```

I want the code to be able to format it properly in the csv file to be able to import the two rows in a database.

[This is the output when I write the data on 'test.csv'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEFIW.png)

[which will result into this when opened up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmaHD.png)

[The expected outcome would be something like this!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPFf4.png)

Comment: And what exactly is your problem? What was the stack trace, or unexpected behavior?

Comment: I am not sure how I can write the output data correctly into a csv file so it's sorted by companyname / location. 
Everything I tried has been futile.

Comment: But my question is *what is your problem*. Did the file not write at all? Did it only write parts? Does it not run and there is an error message? This is important information to include in your post

Comment: There are actually no errors! The code works,
It writes everything into the 'test.csv' file but when I open the CSV file in a text editor the format is wrong. So my problem is figuring out how to format the data properly to write it to a CSV file.

Comment: How is the format wrong? What do you expect it to look like, compared to what it *does* look like. It would be great if you could edit your post to include samples. Based off your print statement you posted I can't tell how it doesn't meet your expectations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how it is improperly formatted, but maybe you just need to replace `with open('test.csv', 'w')` with `with open('test.csv', 'w+', newline='')`

I've combined your code (taking out `htmlrequests` for `requests` and `bs4` modules and also not using `listData`, but instead creating my own lists. I've left your lists but they do nothing):

```
import csv
import bs4
import requests

# Define variables
listData = ['Companies', 'Locations', 'Descriptions']
company_list = []
locations_list = []
plus = 15
max = 30
count = 0

# while loop to repeat process till max is reached

while count <= max:
    start = 'https://www.companiesintheuk.co.uk/find?q=Activities+of+sport+clubs&start={}&s=h&t=SicCodeSearch&location=&sicCode=93120'.format(count)
    res = requests.get(start)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
    for i, div in enumerate(soup.find_all('div', class_="search_result_title")):
        listData[0] = listData[0].strip() + div.text
        company_list.append(div.text.strip())
    for i, div2 in enumerate(soup.find_all('div', class_="searchAddress")):
        listData[1] = listData[1].strip() + div2.text
        locations_list.append(div2.text.strip())
# This is extra information
#        for i, div3 in enumerate(soup.find_all('div', class_="searchSicCode")):
#            listData[2] = listData[2].strip() + div3.text
    count = count + plus

if len(company_list) == len(locations_list):
    with open('test.csv', 'w+', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        writer.writerow(['Name', 'Location'])
        for i in range(len(company_list)):
            writer.writerow([company_list[i], locations_list[i]])
```

Which generates a csv file like:

```
Name,Location
(AMG) AGILITY MANAGEMENT GROUP LTD,"UNITED KINGDOM, M6 6DE"
"(KLA) LIONS/LIONESS FOOTBALL TEAMS WORLD CUP LTD
(Dissolved)","ENGLAND, BD1 2PX"
0161 STUDIOS LTD,"UNITED KINGDOM, HD6 3AX"
1 CLICK SPORTS MANAGEMENT LIMITED,"ENGLAND, E10 5PW"
1 SPORT ORGANISATION LIMITED,"UNITED KINGDOM, CR2 6NF"
100UK LTD,"UNITED KINGDOM, BN14 9EJ"
1066 GYMNASTICS,"EAST SUSSEX, BN21 4PT"
1066 SPECIALS,"EAST SUSSEX, TN40 1HE"
10COACHING LIMITED,"UNITED KINGDOM, SW6 6LR"
10IS ACADEMY LIMITED,"ENGLAND, PE15 9PS"
"10TH MAN LIMITED
(Dissolved)","GLASGOW, G3 6AN"
12 GAUGE EAST MANCHESTER COMMUNITY MMA LTD,"ENGLAND, OL9 8DQ"
121 MAKING WAVES LIMITED,"TYNE AND WEAR, NE30 1AR"
121 WAVES LTD,"TYNE AND WEAR, NE30 1AR"
1-2-KICK LTD,"ENGLAND, BH8 9PS"
"147 HAVANA LIMITED
(Liquidation)","LONDON, EC2M 2PL"
147 LOUNGE LTD,"ENGLAND, LS7 3JB"
147 SNOOKER AND POOL CLUB (LEICESTER) LIMITED,"ENGLAND, LE2 8FN"
1ACTIVE LTD,"UNITED KINGDOM, N18 2QX"
1ON1 KING LTD,"AVON, BS5 0JH"
1PUTT LTD,"UNITED KINGDOM, WC2H 9JQ"
1ST SPORTS LTD,"UNITED KINGDOM, SE18 5SZ"
2 BRO PRO EVENTS LTD,"UNITED KINGDOM, EC1V 2NX"
2 SPLASH SWIM SCHOOL LTD,"ENGLAND, B36 0EY"
2 STEPPERS C.I.C.,"SURREY, CR0 6BX"
2017 MOTO LIMITED,"UNITED KINGDOM, ME2 4NW"
2020 ARCHERY LTD,"LONDON, SE16 6SS"
21 LEISURE LIMITED,"LONDON, EC4M 7WS"
261 FEARLESS CLUB UNITED KINGDOM CIC,"LANCASHIRE, LA2 8RF"
2AIM4 LIMITED,"HERTFORDSHIRE, SG2 0JD"
2POINT4 FM LTD,"LONDON, NW10 8LW"
3 LIONS SCHOOL OF SPORT LTD,"BRISTOL, BS20 8BU"
3 PT LTD,"ANTRIM, BT40 2FB"
3 PUTT LIFE LTD,"UNITED KINGDOM, LU3 2DP"
3 THIRTY SEVEN LTD,"KENT, DA9 9RS"
3:30 SOCCER SCHOOL LTD,"UNITED KINGDOM, EH6 7JB"
30 MINUTE WORKOUT (LLANISHEN) LTD,"PONTYCLUN, CF72 9UA"
321 RELAX LTD,"MID GLAMORGAN, CF83 3HL"
360 MOTOR RACING CLUB LTD,"HALSTEAD, CO9 2ET"
3LIONSATHLETICS LIMITED,"ENGLAND, S3 8DB"
3S SWIM ROMFORD LTD,"UNITED KINGDOM, DA9 9DR"
3XL EVENT MANAGEMENT LIMITED,"KENT, BR3 4NW"
3XL MOTORSPORT MANAGEMENT LIMITED,"KENT, BR3 4NW"
4 CORNER FOOTBALL LTD,"BROMLEY, BR1 5DD"
4 PRO LTD,"UNITED KINGDOM, FY5 5HT"
```

Which seems fine to me, but your post was very unclear about how you expected it to be formatted so I really have no idea

Comment: This is actually what I have been looking for! I have been struggeling for a while now and this is the solution. Thank you man this is a lifesaver!

Comment: @hoyeung Nice! If you are interested in learning the `csv` module (or get stuck trying to deal with csvs in the future) I would recommend reading this page https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html there are other useful features like `csv.DictReader()` or specifying dialects and quotechars!